# Slides with fitimage + textblock + footnote

Tags: beamer

I would like to post here a conflict of beamer using  fitimage + textblock + footnote.
There is a conflict. I am not sure what it is causing it. 
I tried many ideas, but none worked.

An help would be here great.

The example is here below.

Thank you.
I am looking forward to hearing you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,t]{beamer}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{grffile}


% %\usetheme{Madrid}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
% %gets rid of bottom navigation bars, then reset with {}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{\textcolor{white}{\rule{\paperwidth}{5pt}}
}



\usepackage{xparse,calc}
\newlength\fitimageht
\newlength\fitotherht
\newsavebox\fitimagebox
\NewDocumentCommand \fitimage { m m O {} }{%
  \sbox\fitimagebox{%
     \parbox{\textwidth}{%
       #1\par
       #3
    }%
  }%
  \settototalheight{\fitotherht}{%
     \usebox\fitimagebox
  }%
  \setlength\fitimageht{\textheight}%
  \addtolength\fitimageht{-\fitotherht-\topskip-\footskip-3\baselineskip}%
  #1\par
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\fitimageht,keepaspectratio]{#2}\par
  #3}




%\newlength\fitimageht
%\newlength\fitotherht
%\newsavebox\fitimagebox
\NewDocumentCommand \fitimageab { m m m O {} }{%
  \sbox\fitimagebox{%
     \parbox{\textwidth}{%
       #1\par
       #4
    }%
  }%
  \settototalheight{\fitotherht}{%
     \usebox\fitimagebox
  }%
  \setlength\fitimageht{\textheight}%
  \addtolength\fitimageht{-\fitotherht-\topskip-\footskip-3\baselineskip}%
  #1\par
   \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
   \column{.48\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\fitimageht,keepaspectratio]{#2}
   \column{.48\linewidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\fitimageht,keepaspectratio]{#3}
   \end{columns}\par
   #4}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\newcommand{\pagemark}{
\begin{textblock*}{0.45\textwidth}(0.95\textwidth,0.05\textheight)
\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{star.jpg}
\end{textblock*}
}




\begin{document}

%test6
\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\thesection.~\insertsection}
\begin{itemize}
\item Header
\begin{itemize}
\item this is an example

\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\pagemark
\end{frame}



%test
\section{test}
\begin{frame}
\fitimage{
\frametitle{\thesection.~\insertsection}
\begin{itemize}
\item test test
\begin{itemize}
\item test

\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\pagemark
}{test.png}[]
\end{frame}



%section281
\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\thesection.~\insertsection}
\begin{itemize}
\item Header
\begin{itemize}
\item this is an example  \footnote{footnote text}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see a conflict. However, what I can see is that you are loading several packages several times. Also you need not to load `graphicx` nor `color` (maybe this is where your conflict comes from?) and `hyperref` wants to be loaded last. So please clean up your preamble and check whether this helps. If not, describe how this conflict manifests itself. Also when you post such examples avoid using graphics files others don't have, use `example-image-a` etc. instead.

Comment: thank you. I have updated accordingly, it may now show better the issue with fitimage. Is that on your compiler also making an issue with slide with fitimage ... hopefully one can reproduce the issue.

Comment: You still load unnecessary packages like graphicx and color and have `\usepackage{xparse,calc}` and other stuff twice.  And you still include `star.jpg`. I am very very sparse with downvotes but this one deserves one. If you make a real edit to really improve the question, I will be happy to retract it.

Comment: I came for help, not for voting.

Comment: The compilation is done under BSD but it may work under linux, issue comes from : pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (Web2C 2015)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
 
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.36+apng; using libpng 1.6.36+apng
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04

Comment: The error comes because you have an empty line (after `\item test`) in the argument of `\fitimage{...}`.

Comment: well, it compiles well under Linux but fails under BSD. The change to remove the empty line does not help BSD to compile correctly. I am looking forward to hearing you for more ideas...